# How to boot from an .iso file in GRUB2?

Tags: software-recommendation, grub2, iso

Is there a   way for doing this?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Yes, please elaborate on what you mean. This is an interesting topic; booting from an .iso file is potentially very useful.

Comment: i wanted to add a .iso entry in grub2 menu.

Comment: ISOBoot:: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot

Comment: The same topic is discussed [here](http://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be much easier than the impression you get from all the detailed explanations on the web. I just did the following on Ubuntu 12.04 to boot FreeDOS .iso for a firmware update

- Install grub-imageboot
- copy your .iso file(s) to /boot/images/
- run update-grub2

Or copy/paste these:

```
sudo -s
apt-get install grub-imageboot
mkdir /boot/images/
cp $YOUR_ISO_FILE.iso /boot/images/

update-grub2
```

**That's it.**

Sometimes, you may need 2 more steps to do before running update-grub2:

If you never did it before, you need to edit /etc/default/grub so that you see the grub menu on boot:

```
## To show the menu, disable the hidden_timeout, and set a timeout
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

For some .iso images, you may need to add this option in /etc/default/grub-imageboot : (I needed it for my FreeDOS .iso)

```
ISOOPTS="iso raw"
```

If you did edit one of these config. files, you need to run `update-grub2` again.

**Update:** Here is the resulting menuentry asked by "dma_k"

```
menuentry "Bootable ISO Image: SV100S2_64_128_120229" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,msdos6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6ca082d0-63d0-48c3-9e5f-2ce5d7a74fe4
    linux16 /boot/memdisk iso raw
    initrd16 /boot/images/SV100S2_64_128_120229.iso
}
```

This was for a FreeDOS image with some firmware update or such.

Comment: Not working for me on 12.10 iso=>12.10

Comment: @mivk: Could you please also provide the resulting `menuentry` for the given ISO?

Comment: @dma_k: see update above.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Have you found any limitations with this approach? I have a feeling that `memdisk` can only load images say less then 1GB, something more heavy (e.g. Win7 DVD ISO) is causing problems.

Comment: Only ever used this for various small firmware updates.

Comment: Not working Ubuntu 12.04 iso => 12.04.  `update-grub` does say `Found iso image: /boot/images/ubuntu-12.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso`, but when I reboot there is no entry on the GRUB menu.

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you want to add a .iso entry to the GRUB menu and boot it ?

I found [this info](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847) on Ubuntu Forums

Comment: Problem is (as I found out the hard way today) that it's still impossible to install from a grub-mounted iso because the installer crashes when trying to unmount the iso... *sigh

Answer (score 4):

I came across here because I got tired of burning countless bootable ISO 9660 images and thus wanted to use GRUB 2 to bootstrap a FreeDOS one for updating the firmware/microcode of Seagate HDDs. As a complement or alternative to mivk's answer (using `memdisk` of syslinux), the following was what I had done to leverage the power of GRUB 2:

1. Install the *syslinux-common* package (for using `memdisk` within it; grub-imageboot is a non-essential hooking package)
2. Press the 'c' key (mnemonic for command) to activate the command prompt of GRUB 2's builtin mini-shell (or, more precisely, the minimal BASH-like shell)
3. Issue the 3 lines of commands in the GRUB 2's mini-shell:

```
   linux16 (hd0,gpt2)/usr/lib/syslinux/memdisk iso raw
   initrd16 (hd0,gpt3)/myUserAccount/download/Barracuda-ALL-GRCC4H.iso
   boot
   # where Barracuda-ALL-GRCC4H.iso is a FreeDOS-based ISO 9660 image, and 
   # the mathematical 2-tuples or ordered pairs, (hd0,gpt2) and (hd0,gpt3), 
   # are GRUB 2's respective device notations for my rootfs partition 
   # (e.g., /dev/sda2) and home partition (e.g., /dev/sda3).
   # NOTE: This procedure also applies to Seagate's SeaTools (based on 
   #       FreeDOS as well); just substitute the file SeaToolsDOS223ALL.iso 
   #       for Barracuda-ALL-GRCC4H.iso.
```

Information on `memdisk` of syslinux is at http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/MEMDISK

By manipulating commands directly in the mini-shell, this procedure is more flexible and smipler than most of the aforesaid methods since you do not have to bother to tweak and update those GRUB 2's configurations every time you wanna try a different Linux distro or a BSD-based live CD.

Currently, it is these 4 lines of commands that one can use as a generic pattern in the GRUB 2's mini-shell, i.e., the *loopback-linux-initrd-boot* sequence plus some argument(s) passed to the given kernel, for example, to bootstrap as many popular Linux ISO images as possible (in this case is with 3 kernel commandline arguments for System Rescue CD):

```
   loopback lb (hd0,gpt3)/myUserAccount/download/systemrescuecd-x86-3.7.0.iso
   linux (lb)/isolinux/rescue64 isoloop=systemrescuecd-x86-3.7.0.iso setkmap=us docache
   initrd (lb)/isolinux/initram.igz
   boot
```

N.B. The `loopback` part of the generic pattern is not, strictly speaking, mandatory for Linux, when you intend to install a Linux distro such as a Debian derivative without wasting an optical disc.

Answer (score 2):

http://ansi.interblc.com/2010/02/06/howto-boot-iso-images-via-grub2-with-ubuntu/

> 1. Change to the `/etc/grub.d` dir.
> 2. Add your ISO images starting with `50` here. For example my entry for
>      the normal Ubuntu ISO image
>      (50_ubuntu) looks like this:
>
> `echo "Adding $(egrep menu[e]ntry $0 | cut -d'"' -f2)" >&2
>
>       cat << EOF
>
>       menuentry "Ubuntu 10.04 Daily Build" {
>
>         loopback loop (hd0,3)/ansi/software_and_config/ISOs/ubuntu/lucid-desktop-i386.iso
>         linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper
>   iso-scan/filename=/ansi/software_and_config/ISOs/ubuntu/lucid-desktop-i386.iso
>   file=(loop)/preseed/ubuntu.seed quiet
>   splash bootkbd=sg --
>              initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
>
>       }`
>
> My ISO files are stored on sda3 under
>   /ansi/software_and_config/ISOs/ubuntu/.
>   In order to change it for your needs
>   there are 3 elements to change. The
>   loopback line contains your hard disk
>   in grub style (hdx,y  x=0->sda
>   x=1->sdb aso) and the path. The third
>   element to change is in the linux
>   line. Store this file as “50_ubuntu”
>   in “/etc/grub.d“, make it executable
>   with “chmod a+x 50_ubuntu” and
>   activate the changes with
>   “ubdate-grub“. After a reboot you
>   should be able to activate the grub
>   menu with the shift-key and select the
>   new entry.

<sub>*(Note: if someone can use the proper [CODE] formatting, that'd be great. I can't seem to get it to work properly. --tyblu)*</sub>

Comment: As is this answer isn't very great. Could you provide more insight about the link, possibly even creating a summary of the steps or the result?

Comment: In modern versions of GRUB you can just edit /boot/grub/custom.cfg and write menu entries directly there (they're read from 41_custom), which is less hassle.

Comment: Only works for ubuntu, other lininux with modified names

Answer (score 0):

As Mark Rooney said, you can find a [great guide on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1549847).

This will allow you to boot from an ISO file, but only if the ISO supports it. (All recent Ubuntu releases should, as should a number of other distros).

If you plan on installing from the live ISO, you should put the file on a different partition from the one you will be installing to (since you can't write to the partition that you are running off of). Chances are, the installer will complain anyway. What you have to do is manually edit `/etc/mtab` and remove the entry that corresponds to the partition with the ISO file.

Comment: I don't see how this guide helps to boot non-linux-based ISO images, e.g. ISO images that have no `vmlinuz`. Ideas?

Answer (score -1):

To boot from an ISO file on USB disk/stick, **probably the most user-friendly way** is **MultiSystem**: http://liveusb.info/dotclear/index.php?pages/install

You just **drag-and-drop** to have **most** ISO images included in the boot menu of your LiveUSB disk/stick.

Comment: The question is asking how to use grub2 to boot an image file, not put it on a usb stick.

Comment: Unless you want to deter (put off) people from answering questions, you might have kindly considered that people might want to "**boot from an .iso file in GRUB2**" either **(1) on a hard disk** or **(2) (probably more often) on a USB disk/stick**, and I think **my answer offers a good solution to the 2nd scenario** although it may not apply to the 1st scenario, and I have made it clear in the answer. But how do you know that this question refers to a hard disk and **not a USB disk/stick**? In a constructive spirit, you could perhaps say this is a **partial** answer, and not a negative one ;-)