# Adding grub2 menu-entry for iso using grml-rescueboot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, live-usb, iso

Following this [official Ubuntu documentation page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) and the steps outlined under "Creating the grub2 Menuentry - grml-rescueboot", I tried to add an i386 desktop iso of the old Feisty Fawn (7.04) to the entries already present (Windows 7, and Ubuntu 12.04).

Upon reboot, the entry appears fine at the end of the menu list options; but upon clicking it, the computer goes busy briefly, then goes back to the menu.

Any ideas? I don't think it's because of the age of the distro as it should run fine on my netbook (no UEFI, etc.). Did I miss a needed step except for steps 1-3 outlined in the article?

---

If this cannot be remedied: Is there another way of adding an iso to the grub2 menu - without having to manually create a grub2 menuentry which I'd rather avoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to manually add a grub entry as none of the automated tools will generate a menu entry for an .iso .

Second, although grub can "boot" an iso, the iso needs to be customized to be able to boot this way. 7.04 does not contain such customizations.

Personally I do not know what customizations need to be made, I suspect they would be in the kernel and initrd. I asked in #grml (irc) but never got a clear answer.

There is some additional discussion (and links) here - [How to boot from an .iso file in GRUB2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24903/how-to-boot-from-an-iso-file-in-grub2)

Comment: Thanks. Do I understand your "Second" correctly that you believe that it is impossible to boot to Feisty iso when grub2 is the boot loader? I will follow the additional suggestions in the link you kindly added later today.

Comment: It is not possible to boot the feisty iso with grub 2.

Comment: And is it correct that once grub2 handles boot, even if the boot order is changed to the USB (or CD) drive first, I go to the grub menu? (I'm asking as I first tried to simply boot from bootable USB, but kept going to the grub2 menu (with no entry for the USB image, obviously) - or is the image possibly corrupted/burnt with errors on that USB drive?).

Comment: I am not understanding what you are asking now, perhaps a separate question or check the md5 sum of your iso?

Comment: I meant: if (1) grub2 is the boot loader; and (2) before power up, you insert a bootable USB; and (3) change boot order to USB drive: will (a) grub2 take over and prevent the boot from the USB drive; or (b) will you boot from the USB drive? (assuming the drive has no errors, of course. I thought (b) would happen; but in my case (a) happened. If (b) should happen, I need to check what I burnt for errors).

Comment: The boot order is set in your BIOS. Once the boot process is passed to grub, you will keep returning to the grub menu unless grub can pass the process to your boot partition (initrd and vmlinuz)

Comment: There is an automated tool that will do this. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The grml-rescueboot package integrates Grml ISO booting into GRUB. I believe this package first became available around May of 2012.

This package provides a script for update-grub which looks for Grml ISO images in /boot/grml and automatically adds an entry for each image.

I've used this method to create a USB installer with multiple Live media ISOs to allow for "pick and choose" installation.

If you don't have the package you can install it with `sudo apt-get install grml-rescueboot`

Sources: Experience

https://wiki.grml.org/doku.php?id=rescueboot

Comment: thanks for the information. This question is almost 3 years old lol

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes it is. I'm just trying to do my part to keep the answers up to date. ;-)