# Simplest way to get bootable ISO with installed/persistent Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, persistence

Sometimes I need to boot specially setuped Ubuntu and I think that better way to do this - load iso from hdd. I already [know how to boot from iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24903/how-to-boot-from-an-iso-file-in-grub2), but what is the simplest way to get iso that can save my setting for next boot, for example installation of new software? Strange that we can not download such image from official Ubuntu download page, as VM-images too. I found nothing in DuckDuckGo about such type of iso.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

Comment: @kos There is no fast solution to get persistent Ubuntu iso without hour for installing and using usb?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yes but this page have step like `Partitioning Your USB Stick` and `Creating the "casper-rw" File System` - is it possible for `iso`, not for `usb`?

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't even know where I read USB drive in first place.

Comment: No, that is the point of persistence, you need a separate file system to serve as an overlay. I agree with the advice to just perform an installation, will work better.

Comment: why don't you simply configure the .iso to use a particular partition as a home or whatever folder?

Comment: @Gabor because every time the system boots, he would need to reload the home partition, and install software again

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, you want to boot from an ISO residing on your hard drive? You are opposed to booting from a USB stick? If you're willing to go the USb route, you have MKUSB, which is very user-friendly. I ended up using MKUSB, after having some problems with some of the popular live USB installer apps.

If you want to boot (with persistence) from an ISO on your HDD, without installing your Linux distro on the HDD, there is no short answer I can give, though more experienced users might. Therefore I'll take the liberty to point to this link from the Linux Mint forums, but it applies to Ubuntu as well.

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1849

One more thing, you can install an extra distro in another partition(s). It seeems to me to be the most logical way, unless you want a portable Linux, but then USB is the way to go, in my opinion.