# Install a newer version of Ubuntu_Mate from a second hard drive

Tags: ubuntu-mate

Can I install a newer version of Ubuntu_Mate from a second hard drive?

I do not want to install from a pendrive or a DVD.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use any media your machine *firmware* will boot from. I used to use ISOs written to a disk partition, because I still wanted to use a thinkpad with non-working USB ports in QA...  (ie. a script I created would add the ISO entries to the existing boot loader; in your case you can direct your *firmware* to boot whichever device your installation media is on in the manner the *firmware* requires, be is setting or key prior or at boot)

Comment: Also asked at https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/install-newer-verion-of-um-from-a-2nd-hard-drive/27088/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24903/how-to-boot-from-an-iso-file-in-grub2 
 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux   all refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a bootable live cd disk image mounted on the hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121212/using-a-bootable-live-cd-disk-image-mounted-on-the-hard-drive)